# How to convert while loop to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am facing difficulties while converting the below while loop to an arraylist so I can display the values in `selectonemenu` component. The while loop code is:

```
        String date1 = "JAN-2015";
        String date2 = "APR-2015";

        DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");

        Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            beginCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(date1));
            finishCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(date2));


        while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
            String date =     formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(date);
            beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: so what is the difficulty, doesn't `ArrayList.add()` work for you?

Comment: **While loop can not be converted to ArrayList** !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> dateSelections = new ArrayList<>();
while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) 
{
        String date = formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
        dateSelections.add(date);
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

dateSelections should be populated with your possible selections at the end of the while loop.

Comment: I tried to print the values of dateselections it gave me blank values